# How to assign a UIimage while within a block

Tags: ios, url, asynchronous, uiimageview

I'm making a request to a URL to download an image. I receive it as an `NSData` object, but when I try to convert it to a `UIimage with imageWithData:` the `UIImage` is not loaded. Here's my Code

```
__block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
__weak typeof(request)weakRequest = request;
__block UIImage * imager;
__block NSData * image;
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    [self parseXMLFileAtFileId:[weakRequest responseData]];
    if (!files){
        cell.correctImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sidebarPlaceholder"];
    }
    else{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[self downloading:[files objectAtIndex:0]]];
        __block ASIHTTPRequest *requester = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

        __weak typeof(request)weakRequesting = requester;
        [requester setCompletionBlock:^{
            image =  [weakRequesting responseData];
            imager = [UIImage imageWithData:image];
            cell.correctImage.image = imager;
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];
        }];

        [requester startAsynchronous];
    }
}];
```

Previously I got it working by explicitly stating the size of the `UIImageView`, but that should be taken care of by the `UITableviewCell`. How do I get the image to show up?

Comment: Does it work if you force the code that accesses the UI to the main thread with `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`?

Comment: unfortunately not. The way ASIHTTPRequest works is that the block is executed on the main thread after execution asynchronously of the http request

Answer (score 1):

Try to run these block of code in main thread as it appeared you are trying to set the image and updating layout in background thread. Use following `NSThread` method right after

```
UIImage *imager = [UIImage imageWithData:image]

[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImage:) withObject:imager waitUntilDone:false];
```

// Define method to update the image

```
- (void)updateImage: (UIImage *)paramImage {
    cell.correctImage.image = paramImage;
    [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Comment: @Idindu unfortunately this didn't work either as I don't think that the block is being executed in the background thread

Comment: I am bit suspicious about weakRequesting, could you please set breakpoint at "image =  [weakRequesting responseData]" and see if it does receive image data or not?